# How to refer to foreign key without HasForeignKey()

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF 4.0 with the 4.1 upgrade for POCO / code-first.

OK so I have a domain model where type `Car` has, in a collection, multiple objects of type `Part`. So a one:many relation.

```
HasMany(v => v.Parts)
  .WithRequired()
  .HasForeignKey(v => v.CarId)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

The problem with this is that it requires me to add a `CarId` property to my `Part` type. This is leaking ORM detail into my domain model - which is bad. Marking everything virtual is annoying enough.

Looking at the XML doc comment for the `HasForeignKey()` method says this:

> Configures the relationship to use
>   foreign key property(s) that are
>   exposed in the object model.  **If the
>   foreign key property(s) are not
>   exposed in the object model then use
>   the Map method.**

That's great and all. But it introduces a catch-22 situation because if I refactor my `Part` type by removing the `CarId` property that I don't want and update my EF model builder to not bother with mapping that property. Then as you can imagine it means I cannot then call `HasKey()` for defining the composite key, ala:

```
HasKey(v => new { v.CarId, v.PartId });
```

`HasKey()` doesn't appear to support defining the keys based upon non-Property lambdas.

What is the solution here?

Comment: I think your question title should be: "How to define a primary key without having all primary key columns exposed as properties in the model?" Isn't that actually the problem? By killing `CarId` you do not only want to remove the FK property (which is easy) but also a part of your complex PK (which is probably impossible).

Comment: You're right. The key here is that I don't want superfluous "back references" in my domain model. The domain model has no need for them and they just become a pain to keep in-sync. I am surprised that EF seems to require polluting my domain model with back references - which are purely a RDBMS concern.

Comment: You don't need back references in EF, it's optional to expose them. Your problem is that you have a composite primary key and a part of it is a foreign key. Normally you could get rid of a foreign key property but not in your case because it's part of the PK at the same time. And you cannot remove the PK from the model class. Your best option would be to make `PartId` a primary key alone, then you could remove the `CarId`. That's basically what hazimdikenli proposed in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely don't like to have foreign key properties in your model you could remove the convention to detect FK properties to avoid that EF marks properties automatically as FK properties ...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions
        .Remove<NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
}
```

... and then simply don't specify the FK property in your mapping:

```
HasMany(v => v.Parts)
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

You still need `CarId` in your model because it is part of the primary key, but this way it doesn't act anymore as foreign key property.

Just an idea, I am not sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what about adding a new key field to CarParts table like CarPartId, so you would not need the composite key. (Composite Key support is not that great when working with ORMs.)